# Android onTouch recognized on other view

Tags: android, android-view

I have two buttons packed into the same viewgroup - a simple linear layout, like this:

```
      <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/activity_game_circle1"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_circle"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/activity_game_circle2"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:text="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:background="@drawable/orange_circle"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

On the main activity I initialize my buttons and a new on touch listener like that

```
    circle1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_game_circle1);                        
    circle2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_game_circle2);                        
    View.OnTouchListener touch_listener = new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
        {
            return circle_touch(view, motionEvent);
        }
    };
    circle1.setOnTouchListener(touch_listener);
    circle2.setOnTouchListener(touch_listener);
```

"circle_touch" is a simple method that uses two scaling animations (in and out scaling when pressed) like this:

```
    public boolean circle_touch(View circle_view, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
        {
            //  Animation in
            circle_view.startAnimation(animation_in);
        } 
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
        {
            //  Animation out
            circle_view.startAnimation(animation_out);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

A problem occurs when I test this code, after two or three clicks on the same button the other one starts scaling as if I touched it, it does the same vice versa. Is this a bug or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to fix this strange behaviour by putting buttons with the same parent into separate parents, that is adding them linear (or other) layouts like this:

UPDATED XML:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/activity_game_circle1"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_circle"/>
       </LinearLayout>
       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/activity_game_circle2"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:text="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:background="@drawable/orange_circle"/>
        </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```